# php string replace not working

Tags: php, string, youtube

I am running a code which takes a youtube url as input and i am using str_replace on it.

```
$title = str_replace('watch?v=', 'embed/', $title);
```

but the replacement just wont happen. I keep getting the same string back.

The youtube url im using as of now is http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwQx9gw2NfM

what mistake am I making ? The the serch string is CLEARLY present in the url but it wont get replaced.

Or is there a better way to do this ?

EDIT: The code works fine... I was trying to replace the wrong variable

Comment: Why do you hold the url in a variable called `$title` ? -- And otherwise, please show a `bin2hex()` output of its content.

Comment: I copied your code exactly as it appears and the example URL you gave returns `http://www.youtube.com/embed/iwQx9gw2NfM`

Comment: are you sure you are not re-assigning the original value back to $title after the replacement has taken place? There is no reason the code you pasted should not work. Please add more of the surrounding code.

Comment: @mario Thank you man ! Ive been trying to replace the wrong variable...! Just wasted like 30 mins doing nothing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code works fine:

```
$title = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwQx9gw2NfM";

$title = str_replace('watch?v=', 'embed/', $title);

echo $title;  //=> http://www.youtube.com/embed/iwQx9gw2NfM
```

[See it work here on tehplayground](http://tehplayground.com/#IKszsqQQI)

You must have another mistake in your code.  Please paste your context code for additional help.